# Proof by induction that $\sum$ $n\choose k $ $= 2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, permutations, induction, factorial

Trying to prove by induction that

$\sum^{i=n}_{i = 0}$$n\choose i$$=2^n$

So obviously, I prove for some arbitary number, i.e $n = 2$

I then go on to show what the n = k terms look like for the first 3 terms

Then I realise to show that it is the same for $n = k+1$, I need to show that:

$2\times(n=k)\equiv (n=k+1)$

Yet when I try and work out the algebra I keep coming excruciatingly close but to no success, am I going about this proof the wrong way or? I've redone my calculations multiple times so there are no errors in my algebraic simplification.

Could it be that I need to go about this another way instead of trying to show it is $2\times n=k$

Comment: Use $\binom{n}i=\binom{n-1}i+\binom{n-1}{i-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem:
$$2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}1^i1^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}$$

Comment: this is really interesting! can you point me to some sources showing me why what you have written is the case. I never thought about using binomial theorem!

Comment: @user36606 See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: literally just remembered that the choose operation is used to find binomial coefficients, thank you!

Comment: I won't downvote, but this surely is not a proof by induction

Comment: @b00nheT not this is in particular, he's just showing me what I'd use, which is wanted i wanted to know

Comment: @user36606 You are welcome!

Comment: @b00n heT Thank you! It seems that we just had to prove it.